# LibGdx Triangle Collision

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, game-mechanics

I'm back with another question.

I'm trying to get a collision between an actor and a sprite.

With the actor, which only moves upwards and downwards, I've got no problem since it's shape is a rectangle.

But with the other sprite I've got this:

[image]

This sprite moves from the very right part of the screen to the left and resets its position when it reaches the left edge of the screen So the actor moves upwards or downwards to avoid it.

The problem is, I can't use a rectangle as a collision detector for this sprite and I haven't found a proper way to do its collision.

The way I call this triangle and the actor's sprite is this:

texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("texturepack_nuevo.png"));

then, out of that single Texture I get a texture region for both the actor and the triangle sprite.

Comment: We need more explanation/samples/code to be able to help you.

Comment: thanks, ashes! .. I update my post, hopefuly this time I've explained further.

Comment: You probably have to use a polygon, and the `Intersector` class to check for collisions. Some scant details are [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Circles,-planes,-rays,-etc.#polygonscode).